# Размер UICollectionViewController

Tags: swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте, делаю скроллинг для сцен, все работает, вот только размеры все изменились, В GameSceneCollectionViewController.swift размер выставляется так: `let skView = cell.contentView.subviews.first as! SKView` а раньше у меня было так `let skView = self.view as! SKView` так же как раньше сейчас написать не получается, выдает ошибку, как быть? https://yadi.sk/d/DajYTg6AvLsxH

Comment: ничего не понятно. а зачем вы вообще меняли, если раньше работало?

Comment: Раньше у меня просто View была, а сейчас я сделала CollectionViewController

Comment: а можете как то более детально объяснить, типа вот приложение запустилось, на экране то и то, а надо чтоб было это и это. типа такого

Comment: На экране раньше размер объектов был прописано так: `Block.size = CGSize(width: self.view!.bounds.size.width, height: self.view!.bounds.size.height)` а в файле вьюшки, я не знаю как правильно он называется (появляется при создание spritekit) размер сцены был прописан так: `let skView = self.view as! SKView
        let scene = Scene1(size: skView.bounds.size)
        skView.presentScene(scene)`
Сейчас у меня в этом файле со вьюшкой размер сцены прописан так `skView = cell.contentView.subviews.first as! SKView
let scene = Scene1(size: skView.bounds.size)`

Comment: При таком написании в сцене у меня все объекты сплющились

Comment: Надеюсь вы поняли, что я имею ввиду)

Comment: ну после пары минут разбирательства могу сказать, что collectionView работает правильно, размер ячейки тоже правильный, а вот размер SKView где то барахлит. Видимо неправильно указаны constraints. потом еще посмотрю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно изменить размер ячейки в CollectionViewController, то пользуемся делегатом:

> UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

и данной функцией:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

если нужно изменить размер самого CollectionViewController, то вот:

```
collectionView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
```